# Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3→\mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation. Show that there is a line $L$ such that $T(L) = L$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3→\mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation. Show that there is a line $L$ such that $T(L) = L$.

---

I am totally stuck on it.how can I able to solve this problem?please  somebody help.thanks for your kind help.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of T has degree 3, so it has a real root.

Comment: It can be zero. I think this is a problem. Example: T=0.

Comment: still it is not clear to me.can you explain please.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Yeah, there needs to be some invertibility clause or else you can have a zero eigenvalue with eigenspace $L$, and $T(L) = \{0\}$. Otherwise this is true with $T(L) \subset L$.

Comment: @priti Try to solve this problem when you know that $T$ has an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't studied the general theory of eigenvectors and eigenvalues, take into account these facts:

1. Every linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ can be described as $T(X)=AX$, where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. In your case, it is a $3\times 3$ matrix.
2. For a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, with corresponding matrix $A$, the following are equivalent conditions:

(a) There is a line $L$ (that passes through the origin) such that $T(L)=L$

(b) For some nonzero vector $X$ in $L$, $T(X)$ is a nonzero multiple of $X$, that is, there is a nonzero real number $\lambda$ such that $T(X)=\lambda X$

(c) For some nonzero real number $\lambda$, the homogeneous system $(A-\lambda I)X=0$ has a nontrivial solution.

(d) For some nonzero real number $\lambda,\ \det (A-\lambda I)=0$

Now, in the $3\times 3$ case, the polynomial in $\lambda$ (called the characteristic polynomial of $A$) defined as $\det(A-\lambda I)$ has necessarily a real root, but, what if it has only a real root and it is zero? In this case it can't exist a line $L$ such that $T(L)=L$.

Take for example the matrix:
$$A=
 \begin {pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

Then $\det(A-\lambda I)=-\lambda^3-\lambda$, that has roots $0,i,-i$, so in this case the corresponding linear transformation:
$$T(x,y,z)=(0,-z,y) $$
cannot send a line $L$ onto itself.